# Adding to localStorage with JavaScript and Jade

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, backbone.js, pug

Having issues with Jade and the way the data is passed to it when it is rendered.

I am trying to save the data which is in `[{key1: "val1", key2: "val2"}, ...}];`
format but having issues as it shows up as the result below.

Result

```
key: xyz value:[{&quot;artist&quot;:&quot;Lady Gaga&quot;,...
```

This is the code I am working with on the server-side Node.js which is passing it fine ...

```
res.render('musics', {
    title: 'site',
    result: JSON.stringify(result)
});
```

This is the code I am having issues with because of the way I have to call result in jade...

```
script
    function local (arr) {
        var i;
        i = "#{result}";
        localStorage.setItem('xyz', i);
    }
    console.log('stored');
    local();
```

The quotes around result are messing it up but without them I get an error for unexpected identifier...

Any suggestions or if it might be better to go an ajax route through Backbone(which is what I am using with the client-side) I am willing to, just to put some pointers out - the data is being scraped and through selections of a form post - so the data comes back after the post and is a on time transfer, so if I did an ajax call it would have to include the post and the get, otherwise i am not sure of how to receive it... maybe res.json(result) on the server side, but then the page needs to render somehow... Open to suggestions. Thanks! Ultimately I want it to go into localStorage without the " around everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your jade snippet should look like this then:

```
script!= "(function() {localStorage.setItem('xyz',JSON.stringify(" +result + ");})();"
```

by using != you tell jade to not escape the following content, and on the clientside you have to stringify **again** before puting your data to local storage.

Comment: I use this but give them an error `setItem` not defined @greelgorke

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement to @greelgork's answer:

**This is for JSON array**

```
script!= "(function() {var items = []; items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Stored_items')); console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); items.push(" + JSON.stringify(product) + "); localStorage.setItem('Stored_items', JSON.stringify(items)); })();"
```

Anyways, pushing an item into `localStorage` needs to be `stringified` before inserted into `localStorage` hence, @greelgorke's answer should be modified so:

**single item**

```
script!= "(function() {localStorage.setItem('xyz',JSON.stringify(result)); })();"
```

So the `JSON.stringify` is outside the  `string` just like all the other `javascript` code is,
This is what I use in my project and it worx

**Credit** [Push JSON Objects to array in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 if usersList.length
        script.
          const userList = !{JSON.stringify(usersList)}
          localStorage.setItem('xyz',JSON.stringify(userList))
          const loader = document.querySelector(".loader"); 
          loader.className +=" hidden";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).