# Cannot push objects in array in localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html, local-storage

I am trying to store localStorage value in array and following this page [Push JSON Objects to array in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage). My code is:

```
function SaveDataToLocalStorage(data)
{
 var a = [];
 // Parse the serialized data back into an aray of objects
 a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
 // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
 a.push(data);
 // Alert the array value
 alert(a);  // Should be something like [Object array]
 // Re-serialize the array back into a string and store it in localStorage
 localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

where `data` is:

```
 var data = {name: "abc", place: "xyz"}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of null
```

Can anybody show the correct method to store localStorage values in array?

Comment: The variable "a" must be null. Use the debugger in your browser and check the value before the push call is run. I think that should put you on the right track

Answer (score 7, accepted):

null is a special value for objects that aren't initialized to anything. 
My guess is that localStorage.getItem('session') is empty.

a more robust answer would be something like

```
function SaveDataToLocalStorage(data)
{
    var a;
    //is anything in localstorage?
    if (localStorage.getItem('session') === null) {
        a = [];
    } else {
         // Parse the serialized data back into an array of objects
         a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
     }
     // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
     a.push(data);
     // Alert the array value
     alert(a);  // Should be something like [Object array]
     // Re-serialize the array back into a string and store it in localStorage
     localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Comment: `var a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')) || [];`

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the initial empty array that initializes "a" when you fetch the local storage contents. The variable is declared and initialized:

```
var a = [];
```

and then that empty array is immediately thrown away:

```
a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
```

After that, it appears that your retrieved value is actually empty (`null`) if you're getting that error.

If you want "a" to be *either* a new empty array, or else an array saved in local storage, you'd do something like this:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem('session') || "[]";
a = JSON.parse(a);
```

Comment: @user2567857 the problem may be that you're not actually saving the object successfully.

Comment: You mean the variable `data` ?

Comment: @user2567857 no - if "a" is ending up `null` then that means that there wasn't anything in local storage with the key "session".

Comment: Yeah, that it because the solution I am following (as pointed out in my question), is doing `getItem` first and then `setItem`

Comment: @user2567857 OK answer extended with a possibility.

Comment: It's showing `Unexpected token H ` error in line `a = JSON.parse(a);
` if I set `var a` as recommended by you

Comment: @user2567857 well what's in local storage then?  Do a `console.log(a)` right before that line.