# Storing elements in an array in Local Storage using Angular Local Storage Module

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I just need to store an array in `localStorage` and keep adding elements to that array so I could retrieve that stored array in my application. This must be a very simple thing to do with [Angular Local Storage Module](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) but it has got me troubling quite a bit, and I am hoping to get some help on this.

Following is the angular code I have that I am using to store a `queries` into `localStorage` using `angular-local-storage` module:

```
.factory('QueryService', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
        var queries = [];
        var factory = {};

        factory.addQuery = function(query) {
            queries.push(query);

            localStorageService.set('queries', queries);
            return localStorageService.get("queries");
        };
        return factory;
    }])
```

Every time I add a query to the `queries` array, I get only the last element added returned in the result. So basically, `localStorageService.get("queries")` is giving me the last element added to the `queries` array.

Could somebody please help me understand that why am I getting only the last element I am adding to the `queries` array returned?

**EDIT:**
After each element I am adding to the `queries` array I am refreshing the browser.

Comment: Does the _AngularJS_ localStorage module automatically `stringify` and `parse` your array for you. It's my understanding that localStorage only supports strings at this time. Therefore a conversion is needed (usually using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`). I wrote this up in a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage/16084772#16084772) (outside of _AngularJS_). Not sure if the pre-built module covers that for you or not...

Comment: With regards to your edit, are you refreshing the browser before or after you store the contents in localStorage?

Comment: @SnareChops & @War10ck: Is it possible that refreshing the browser in between adding new elements to the `queries` array cleans up the `queries` array?

Comment: @War10ck: I am not sure about that, let me try it that way as well.

Comment: @War10ck: Yes, I need to do that before I add each element to the array.

Comment: Shouldnt var queries = localStorageService.get("queries");

Comment: In answer to your question above in the comments yes, this is entirely possible. If you want the `queries` array to keep all the data (old and new) you'll need to first try and fetch the queries array from localStorage. If it exists, pull the existing content into an array, update the array and push all of the contents back into localStorage. If it's not in localStorage (indicating this is the first iteration of the process) create the array, fill in the new value and push it to localStorage. For all successive requests you'll need to repeat the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can not store arrays directly with localStorage. But angular-local-storage does this work for you as seen on this line: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/blob/ed422c04764d4981a48f4c40859d65087b1b9838/src/angular-local-storage.js#L119

The clue to answer your question is that you are refreshing your browser after adding an element, so the queries array does indeed get cleaned up. A browser refresh actually wipes out all of your JavaScript values and the controller even your whole AngularJS application gets restarted.

To make your code work you have to initialize the queries array in the first line of your controller:

```
.factory('QueryService', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
        var queries = localStorageService.get('queries') || [];
        var factory = {};

        factory.addQuery = function(query) {
            queries.push(query);

            localStorageService.set('queries', queries);
            return localStorageService.get("queries");
        };
        return factory;
    }])
```