# How to store JSON with array in a localStorage (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html

I am developing a game in HTML5 for my project, my problem is in the scoring system.
I want to display the top ten best scorers (already sorted). I am currently working with Array in a JSON.

Now I want to save JSON Array in localStorage

```
var storage = '{"Players":[' +
        '{"score":"0","Name":"Player 2"},' +
        '{"score":"0","Name":"Player 4"},' +
        '{"score":"0","Name":"Player 1"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(storage);

obj['Players'].push({"score": 13,"Name": "Player1"});
obj['Players'].push({"score": 523,"Name": "Player2"});
obj['Players'].push({"score": 3,"Name": "Player3"});
obj['Players'].push({"score": 1235,"Name": "Player4"});

storage = JSON.stringify(obj);

var sortColumnScore = "score";

function SortByScore(x,y) {
    return ((x[sortColumnScore]  == y[sortColumnScore]) ? 0 : ((x[sortColumnScore] < y[sortColumnScore]) ? 1 : -1 ));
}

obj.Players.sort(SortByScore);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById("s"+ (i+1)).innerHTML =
    obj.Players[i].score;
    document.getElementById("p"+ (i+1)).innerHTML =
    obj.Players[i].Name;
};
```

Comment: there's no code there regarding local storage.

Comment: I dunno where should i start with the localStorage.
That's why i'm looking for some help. :)

Comment: so the code snippet is totally irrelevant, just checking

Comment: read the answer would be my first piece of advice

Comment: Why you want to use *localstorage* ?

Comment: @RayonDabre So that i can store the best scores even if i close the browser. 
It is possible right?

Comment: @DarbsLingo, But the scoreboard may change as other users will play the game, isn't it ? If you access the score from `localStorage` then it will never update..

Comment: @RayonDabre Hmmm . thats my next problem now.
Can you please help me ? Please ? :'(

Comment: @DarbsLingo, Store the users score in the _database_ and manipulate users scoreboard at server-side..

Comment: @RayonDabre Btw, the requirement for my project is offline game. :(

Comment: @DarbsLingo. All right! Best of luck..

Comment: Jeez. How can i do this ? :(

Comment: @DarbsLingo - Well explained here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage

Answer (score 2):

Basically you should use localstorage just like you are doing with `storage` above. You can use localstorage in the object way as is doing @Magus or in the associative-array way, calling its primitives `getItem`, `setItem`.

**Simple usage:**

```
var storage = '{"Players":[' +
    '{"score":"0","Name":"Player 2"},' +
    '{"score":"0","Name":"Player 4"},' +
    '{"score":"0","Name":"Player 1"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(storage);

obj['Players'].push({"score": 13,"Name": "Player1"});
obj['Players'].push({"score": 523,"Name": "Player2"});
obj['Players'].push({"score": 3,"Name": "Player3"});
obj['Players'].push({"score": 1235,"Name": "Player4"});

localStorage.setItem('Players', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Then get data from localStorage calling:

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Players'));
```

**Advanced usage:**

For correct usage (coupled with the current user session) and initialization of localstorage/sessionstorage (according to your goal) see the comment of @War10ck following this issue [Push JSON Objects to array in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage).

Comment: If i refresh the page, will the data remain or not ?

Comment: For such questions please see the documentation cited by @Buzinas [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Anyway, the localStorage keeps data even if you close the window and reopen it later. The sessionStorage keeps data only in the same session (i.e. same tab of the browser), instead.

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage can't contains object or array. But you can convert it in a string.

```
// Store the object
localStorage.myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);

// Read the object
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.myObject);
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can i access it again so that i can sort it and display it in my project?

Comment: Use the line `Read the object`

Comment: After i parse the object, can i access the array like this again? 

`obj.Players[0].score`

Comment: Okay, i'll try it. 
I will just comment if it works . thanks (Y)

Comment: @Magus although it will work, it won't work if he refreshes the page, since that's not a correct way to use localStorage. If you set items to the localStorage like this, you're only creating a property into it, as you could do `window.myObject =`, or `document.myObject =` etc.

Comment: It works like this too. See this response : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage?rq=1

Comment: @Buzinas That's my next problem. Would you mind helping me? T.I.A (y)

Answer (score 0):

Getting an item from [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
var str = localStorage.getItem('my-item');
```

Saving an item in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem('my-item', str);
```

---

Note: You can only save strings to the localStorage, so, you will need to convert your data to string via `JSON.stringify` and then use `JSON.parse` when retrieving the strings from localStorage.

Comment: After i parse it, can i access the object again like this ? `obj.Players[i].score`

Comment: @DarbsLingo yeah, you can :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// To store object into local storage
localStorage.setItem('any-unique-key', JSON.stringify(arrayName));


// To retrieve from local storage
var resultArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('any-unique-key') || '{}'); 


// Check if the data associated with that 'any-unique-key' exists or not
// If not then return empty JSON object enclosed with single quotes
return '{}'
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the top answer, except for that `|| '{}'`. To improve your answer it would better to explain the difference/benefit of using your way compared to the existing 6 years old answer... Please [edit] your answer with that information

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I've updated my answer, just let me know if the explanation is correct or not.